# Migration SharePoint 2010 to 2013 - Document set inheritance

Tags: sharepoint, migration, document-set

I've recently migrated a 2010 site to 2013.  One of the document libraries contains a collection of content types that extends the base document set content type.

Although when I go to the document set view (for the extended CT), the view does not render the scroll bars and in turn, I can't scroll.

When I create a new OOB document set, there doesn't seem to be any problems.

And when I create a new custom content type that extends the OOB document set, it also does not have any issues.

I suspect that during the upgrade process, it had modified the base Document Set content type for use in 2013....but not the ones that originally extended off of it.

Just not sure what I can do to fix it.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

False Alarm!

It looks as though that in the past I implemented the FixRibbonAndWorkspaceDimensions() that was used in 2010 to help fix the ribbon to the top of the screen.

When I removed it..... everything was right in the world.